# Saving drag position in localstorage issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, draggable, gridifier

I am using a grid layout plugin, [Gridifier](http://gridifier.io/), that has a dragging and re-ordering function. The order of the items is set using the attribute *data-gridifier-item-id*

I have set up some code to get the original order *data-gridifier-item-id* and the new order *data-gridifier-item-id* and save it to localstorage. I can see in my console that both of these are changing as I drag the items to new positions but they are not sorted based on localstorage when I reload the page.

I am a novice and not able to see what I am missing in getting this to happen. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my example  [Codepen](http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/KpLvxQ?editors=001)

```
//Gridifier code
var grid = $(".gallery");
var settings = {
     "class": "item",
      grid: "vertical", // default = "vertical"
 dragifier: true, // default = false
 dragifierMode: "intersection"
 }
 var asyncGrid = new Gridifier(grid, settings );
  asyncGrid.append(asyncGrid.collectNew());


//LocalStorage Code

 $( function() {

 var gridifier = asyncGrid.collectNew();

 var newSortOrder = []; // global variable for saving order, used later
 var storedSortOrder = localStorage.getItem('sortOrder');
 if ( storedSortOrder ) {
 storedSortOrder = JSON.parse( storedSortOrder );
 // create a hash of items by their gridifier-item-id
 var itemsByGridifierIndex = {};
 var gridifierIndex;
 for ( var i=0, len = gridifier.length; i < len; i++ ) {
  var item = gridifier[i];
  gridifierIndex = $( item).attr('data-gridifier-item-id');
  itemsByGridifierIndex[ gridifierIndex ] = item;
  }
  // overwrite  item order
  i = 0; len = storedSortOrder.length;
 for (; i < len; i++ ) {
  gridifierIndex = storedSortOrder[i];
  item = itemsByGridifierIndex[ gridifierIndex ];
 }
}
 function orderItems() {
 var itemElems = gridifier
 // reset / empty oder array
 newSortOrder.length = 0;
 for (var i=0; i< gridifier.length; i++) {
  newSortOrder[i] = gridifier[i].getAttribute("data-gridifier-item-id");
 }
 // save  ordering
 localStorage.setItem('sortOrder', JSON.stringify(newSortOrder) );
 }

 asyncGrid.onDragEnd(function(sortedItems) {
 orderItems();
 //console.log(gridifier);
 console.log( storedSortOrder);
 console.log(newSortOrder)

//show gridifier-item-id number for testing  
$(gridifier).each(function(){
var gridnumber = $(this).attr("data-gridifier-item-id")
 $(this).text(gridnumber);
});

});
});
```

Comment: Do you mean your items are not sorted (onload) to the way they were saved? That is because you aren't actually sorting them onload, your `// overwrite  item order` code is just overwriting the `item` variable, and that is all. Overwriting that variable does not change the element contained in the variable.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That supports my novice statement